# Word Merge Syntax Errors

Tags: syntax, merge, ms-word, ms-office, formula

I am getting " $!Syntax Error, «." when trying to use the formula below with Office 2013. Any word merge formula gurus out there that could perhaps help me out?

```
{ = { MERGEFIELD BAL } + 10.00 + { MERGEFIELD PAMT} - { MERGEFIELD POS } - 10.00 - { MERGEFIELD JAMT } \# "#, ##0.00" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
{ = { MERGEFIELD  BAL } + 10.00 + { MERGEFIELD  PAMT } - { MERGEFIELD  POS } - 10.00 - { MERGEFIELD  JAMT } \# "#,##0.00" }
```

The only difference I see --- there is a space in your number format. That doesn't seem like it should matter. I'm using Word 2010.